# How can I get this form submit to work properly?

Tags: php, html, forms

The following code is what I am using to e-mail me the contents of a form.
I am having two problems with it and was hoping someone could help.

1. I have checkboxes on the form, and when multiple boxes of the same
   group are checked, the e-mail I receive only shows the last box that
   was checked and not all that were checked.
2. I have a `<textarea>` on
       the form and it doesn't show up in the e-mail sent to me either.

The PHP code:

```
<?php

header('Location: thank-you.html'); 

$from = $_POST['email'];
$to = 'email@example.com';
$subject = "subject";

$message = "";
foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v)
{
    if (!empty($message)) { $message .= "\n\n"; }
    $message .= ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$k)).": ".$v;
}

$headers = "From: $from";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is not with your php, but with your form which you haven't posted.

Comment: where is your form code?

Answer (score 1):

you probably have checkbox groups like this:

```
<input type=checkbox name=box value='one'>
<input type=checkbox name=box value='two'>
```

when they should look like this (with square brackets after the name)

```
<input type=checkbox name=box[] value='one'>
<input type=checkbox name=box[] value='two'>
```

php will then store the values in an array in `$_POST['box']`, which you can then join into comma delimited string inside your existing print code somewere with `implode(', ', $_POST['box'])` for formatting.

Comment: Thanks! How would I add that into the php? I know nothing about php. Do you know why the <textarea> wouldn't be showing up?